# Symfony2 - Accessing tag array which has values is giving an error

Tags: arrays, symfony, tags, tag-cloud

I am trying to use a getTags() array which is an array of arrays into another method GetTagWeights($tags) but am getting an error when using it with this line:

`$tagWeights[$tag] = (isset($tagWeights[$tag['tag']])) ? $tagWeights[$tag['tag']] + 1 : 1;`

I get the following error:

`ContextErrorException: Warning: Illegal offset type in /var/www/html/Satori/src/Symfony/AcmeBundle/Entity/TagRepository.php line 34`

**Question: What am I doing wrong here, I've dumped getTags() and there is data?**

My process is getting tags then weighting the tags for popularity. Tag is setup as a ManyToMany/ManyToMany entity with a Blog entity.

**getTags and getTagWeight methods (dumping $tags from getTags() returns an array of arrays)**

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
array (size=1)
  'tag' => string 'Tag 1' (length=5)
  1 => 
array (size=1)
  'tag' => string 'Tag 2' (length=5)
  2 => 
array (size=1)
  'tag' => string 'Tag 3' (length=5)


public function getTags()
{
$tags = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->select('t.tag')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();

return $tags;
}

public function getTagWeights($tags)
{
$tagWeights = array();

if (empty($tags))
    return $tagWeights;

foreach ($tags as $tag)
{
    $tagWeights[$tag] = (isset($tagWeights[$tag['tag']])) ? $tagWeights[$tag['tag']] + 1 : 1;
}

// Shuffle the tags
uksort($tagWeights, function() {
    return rand() > rand();
});

$max = max($tagWeights);

// Max of 5 weights
$multiplier = ($max > 5) ? 5 / $max : 1;

foreach ($tagWeights as &$tag)
{
    $tag = ceil($tag * $multiplier);
}

return $tagWeights;
}
```

**Controller**

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$tags = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Tag')
    ->getTags();

$tagWeights = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Tag')
    ->getTagWeights($tags);
// var_dump($tagWeights); die();
return array(
    'tags' => $tagWeights,
);
```

**Tag entity**

```
class Tag
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tag", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $tag;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Blog", mappedBy="tags")
 */
protected $blogs;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->blogs = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set tag
 *
 * @param string $tag
 * @return Tag
 */
public function setTag($tag)
{
    $this->tag = $tag;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tag
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTag()
{
    return $this->tag;
}

/**
 * Add blogs
 *
 * @param \AcmeBundle\Entity\Blog $blogs
 * @return Tag
 */
public function addBlog(\AcmeBundle\Entity\Blog $blogs)
{
    $this->blogs[] = $blogs;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove blogs
 *
 * @param \AcmeBundle\Entity\Blog $blogs
 */
public function removeBlog(\AcmeBundle\Entity\Blog $blogs)
{
    $this->blogs->removeElement($blogs);
}

/**
 * Get blogs
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getBlogs()
{
    return $this->blogs;
}
}
```

**This is how I am accessing tags in twig:**

```
{% for tag, weight in tags %}
    <span class="weight-{{ weight }}"><a href="{{ path('AcmeBundle_tag', { 'tag': tag.tag }) }}">{{ tag.tag }}</a></span>
{% else %}
    <p>There are no tags</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why did you delete and repost this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644392/symfony2-unable-to-access-tag-array-in-foreach-loop#23644392 ? You can edit your question instead.

Comment: Stop asking the same question over and over again!

Comment: I am trying to find a solution. It's not my intention to ask the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> Arrays and objects *can not* be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: *Illegal offset type*.

You are trying to use `$tag` as key here:

```
$tagWeights[$tag] = (isset($tagWeights[$tag['tag']])) ? $tagWeights[$tag['tag']] + 1 : 1;
```

but because `$tag` is an array, you get an error.

I guess you wanted to do this:

```
$tagWeights[$tag['tag']] = (isset($tagWeights[$tag['tag']])) ? $tagWeights[$tag['tag']] + 1 : 1;
```

Comment: Exactly that. Solutions? What can I do to make this work? Originally, this code works for a single array. See here - http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/customising-the-view-more-with-twig.html under TagCloud. My thoughts are that since Tags are an entity and not a property of blog it's causing issues. Any way around this?

Comment: Have you tried the second line of code in my answer?

Comment: Oh, and, are you sure that your `$tag` variables are arrays? If they are objects, you should use `$tag->getTag()` instead of `$tag['tag']` - see my updated answer.

Comment: When I dump $tags from getTags() I get the arrays in arrays which is in the question. `array (size=6)
  0 => 
array (size=1)
  'tag' => string 'Tag 1' (length=5)
  1 => 
array (size=1)
  'tag' => string 'Tag 2' (length=5)
  2 => 
array (size=1)
  'tag' => string 'Tag 3' (length=5)` And when I tried using $tag->getTag() I get following error: `FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getTag() on a non-object in /var/www/html/Symfony/src/AcmeBundle/Entity/TagRepository.php line 35`

Comment: OK, so I was wrong, it *is* an array an *not* an object. ...but have you tried the second line of code from my answer yet???

Comment: Yes, I tried using `$tagWeights[$tag->getTag()] = (isset($tagWeights[$tag->getTag()])) ? $tagWeights[$tag->getTag()] + 1 : 1;` That's the error I just reported in my comment. And tried `$tagWeights[$tag] = (isset($tagWeights[$tag['tag']])) ? $tagWeights[$tag['tag']] + 1 : 1;`

Comment: **That's not the second line of code in my answer.** Try again. Hint: it's the one that starts with `$tagWeights[$tag['tag']] =`

Comment: Using `$tagWeights[$tag['tag']] = (isset($tagWeights[$tag['tag']])) ? $tagWeights[$tag['tag']] + 1 : 1;` gives me this error: `Impossible to access an attribute ("tag") on a string variable ("Tag 6") in AcmeBundle:Page:footer.html.twig at line 77`

Comment: **1. That's not the second line of code in my answer, that's the original code that comes directly from your question.** **2. You have changed something else in your code, because `$tag` used to be an array, but now contains a string.** -Edit- I see you updated your comment. *That's* the correct line of code. However, it still looks like you have changed something else in your code, because `$tag` is now suddenly a string instead of an array.

Comment: In my latest comment I tried what you mentioned. In my question I used this `$tagWeights[$tag] = (isset($tagWeights[$tag['tag']])) ? $tagWeights[$tag['tag']] + 1 : 1;`

Comment: Only things that were changed were the suggestions provided by you. Everything else remained the same as listed in the question.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry. In that case, it seems like `$tags` is an array of arrays at one point, and an array of strings at another point. That doesn't work. Make sure that `$tags` either contains only arrays, or only strings.

Comment: Cheers Nic, thanks for your time and verbal lashing. :)